# How to pass in the directory that you have been run from to an executable in VB

Tags: vb.net

This may be simple but I have brain freeze on just now

If I cd into a directory from a command line and then run my executable VB.net application, is there a way to detect the directory that it was launched from.

I currently have the executable in my PATH however ideally the person would cd into the directory that they were wanting the executable to act upon.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IO.Directory.GetWorkingDirectory() will get you the directory you CD'd to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

[Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) gives you that information. Note that this property is also assignable, so you can change the current working directory by assigning a new value to it.